# How to multiply 2 images in JavaCV

Tags: image, opencv, javacv, multiplication, iplimage

I currently have a binary black and white image that I have used `cvThreshold` on, and I would like to get the color back on the white part of the image.

From my understanding multiplying the original image with the binary image will result in this effect. I am however unsure how to do that. I am using JavaCV. Ive attempted to:

```
IplImage img.mul(im2);
```

And that hasn't really worked. How do I use the `mul` openCV function with JavaCV? Also if anyone has tips on generally converting opencv code to JavaCV I would be very grateful, the little there is on the JavaCV project page is barely enough to keep me afloat.

Comment: The JavaCV API is pretty similar to the C API and there are loads of examples out there.

Comment: [This might help.](http://note.sonots.com/OpenCV/MatrixOperations.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have my own (maybe quite strange :)..) way to find functions working in JavaCV, but in many cases it works. There's OpenCV's wrapper for C# named emguCV , which have very similar functions to this in JavaCV. So if I want e.g find multiplying or adding function I write in google: `cvMul emgu` or something similar,and here is result of my searching:

[Wiki emgu link 1](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/e912149c-e4ca-5742-3a23-6e501ade666c.htm)

[Wiki emgu link 2](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/db6ff03d-0e6d-64dd-2c1e-6b7507c1a047.htm)

So If you want to multiply 2 IplImages you could do something like that:

```
 IplImage Red=IplImage.create(zdj1.cvSize(),8,1); 
 IplImage Green=IplImage.create(zdj1.cvSize(),8,1);
 IplImage Result=IplImage.create(zdj1.cvSize(),8,1);
          cvMul(Red,Green,Result,1);
```